# Getting chown(): Operation not permitted while running uwsgi from ini file

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

I am trying to run nginx and uwsgi.
When I try to run uwsgi with below command in my proj virtual environment with proj user I get an error. When I run uwsgi, I see the `proj.sock` is created in `/run/uwsgi/proj.sock`
I changed the `/run/uwsgi` permissions to `drwxrwxrwx`  to see if the problem is permission related. But problem still appears. I also checked the `/etc/passwd` and there is no uwsgi user.

The directory info for `/run/uwsgi` is :

```
drwxrwxrwx   2 root           root             60 Jul 16 10:53 uwsgi
```

When I try to change ownership of sock file with proj user to proj:nginx in proj virtual nvironment I get the error below.

```
chown: changing ownership of ‘/run/uwsgi/proj.sock’: Operation not permitted
```

When I check `/run/uwsgi/proj.sock`  file  it is `proj:proj` but it should be changed to `proj:nginx`. This operation can be done manually with root. But it cannot be done with proj user.

Run below command:

```
uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi/sites/proj.ini
```

Error :

```
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /etc/uwsgi/sites/proj.ini<br>
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.15 (64bit) on [Mon Jul 16 10:53:02 2018] ***<br>
compiled with version: 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28) on 13 July 2018 17:12:50<br>
os: Linux-3.10.0-862.6.3.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jun 26 16:32:21 UTC 2018<br>
nodename: localhost.localdomain<br>
machine: x86_64<br>
clock source: unix<br>
detected number of CPU cores: 2<br>
current working directory: /home/proj<br>
detected binary path: /home/proj/Env/proj/bin/uwsgi<br>
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!<br>
chdir() to /home/proj/work/proj<br>
your processes number limit is 4096<br>
your memory page size is 4096 bytes<br>
detected max file descriptor number: 1024<br>
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes<br>
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)<br>
chown(): Operation not permitted [core/utils.c line 2623]<br>
VACUUM WARNING: unix socket /run/uwsgi/proj.sock changed inode. Skip removal
```

My `proj.ini` file for uwsgi ini configuration is :

```
[uwsgi]
py-autoreload = 2
project = proj
username = proj
base = /home/%(username)
chdir = %(base)/%(project)
home = %(base)/Env/%(project)
module = %(project).wsgi:application
master = true
processes = %k
uid = %(username)
socket = /run/uwsgi/%(project).sock
chown-socket = %(username):nginx
chmod-socket = 666
vacuum = true
#logto = /var/log/uwsgi/%(project).log
```

Comment: When i remove "chown-socket = %(username):nginx" uwsgi starts. So i think this line causes problem.

Answer (score 6):

A user can only set the group of a file to a group he is in. In this case your user `proj` is not in the `nginx` group, so it is not allowed to make that change. If you add the user to the `nginx` group (and relogin) then it should work.

Also, setting the directory permissions to `777` allows any user to create and delete files in that directory, and `666` for the socket allows any user to access it. You probably don't want that. More reasonable would be to have `/run/uwsgi` owned by root:nginx with mode `770`, and `chmod-socket = 660` in your project ini.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem.
The socket files were in `/run/uwsgi` directory.

I gave the related project user right to write read execute on this folder.

```sh
setfacl -m u:projuser:rwx /run/uwsgi/
```

Answer (score -1):

As suggested by "ivbtar", I just removed following lines from uwsgi.ini file and it started working,

```
chown-socket = %(username):nginx
chmod-socket = 666
```